# Is there a way to copy code from the Eclipse IDE without the rich-text formatting?

Tags: eclipse, ide, formatting, richtext

Recently every time I copy a block of code from Eclipse and paste the code into TextEdit or a online forum using the code tags, I get the code with the rich-text or html formatting, so I have to copy into a text editor remove the formatting copying and pasting again, In the past this was not a problem I used to copy from eclipse and paste the code without any formatting at all just as plain-text, I dont know if I turn on a property or what I did for this to happen, any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: the rich formatting from a SWT editor seems to have always been available ([bug 64498](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=64498)).

You could use "[Edit, Paste and Match Style](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1086209&seqNum=3)" in TextEdit.

> From the Edit menu, choose **Paste and Match Style**,
>   or use the keyboard shortcut, <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Option Command</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd>.
>
> The pasted text will pick up all the formatting from the character to the left of the flashing insertion point. This technique works in Mail as well.

Answer (score 8):

There is an Eclipse bug filed for this that can be voted for:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=45969

It has been open for 10 years though!

There are applications out there that think they can handle rich text but can't. So for those it looks like we'll have to carry on with "Copy-Switch to Notepad-Paste-Select All-Copy-Switch to final app-Paste" for some time yet.

Comment: Maybe we can ask for a feature in eclipse with a hotkey for copy-switch to notepad-paste-select all-copy. :-)

Comment: Here's a Windows application that I've been using for years now and recommend, which will strip rich text content from the clipboard contents with the press of a hotkey: http://stevemiller.net/puretext/